# Caused by: android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views

Tags: android

I am trying to write a program to parse the given xml. However, it throws that error message:"**Caused by: android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.** "
This is my code

```
    package com.example.xmlparserdeneme;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory;

import org.xml.sax.Attributes;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    ArrayList<String> titles = new ArrayList<String>();
    Context ctx = this;
    CustomAdapter adapter = null;
    ListView lv;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ((Activity) ctx).setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        new parseXML().execute();

        Log.i("info2", titles.toString());

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    class parseXML extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        MySaxHandler handler;

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
            SAXParser parser = null;
            try {
                parser = spf.newSAXParser();
            } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (SAXException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            handler = new MySaxHandler();

            try {
                parser.parse(
                        "/xmlParserDeneme/src/Database.xml",
                        handler);
            } catch (SAXException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            Log.i("info", titles.toString());
            return "a";

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

            lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
            lv.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter(titles, ctx));
        }

        public ArrayList<String> getArray() {
            return titles;
        }

        public class MySaxHandler extends DefaultHandler {

            StringBuffer chars;

            public void startElement(String uri, String localName,
                    String qName, Attributes atts) {
                chars = new StringBuffer();

            }

            public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName)
                    throws SAXException {

                if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("description"))
                    titles.add(chars.toString());

            }

            public void characters(char ch[], int start, int length) {
                chars.append(new String(ch, start, length));
            }

        }

    }
}
```

I am new at android, I don't know where to change. 
I'd be appreciated if anyone tell me how to fix it?

Comment: this happen when you update ui from another thread. Also remove this `((Activity) ctx).setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)`.

Comment: also what is this `"/xmlParserDeneme/src/Database.xml"` where is your Database.xml?

Comment: @Raghunandan, my database is a plist file.

Comment: what is the path of the file. is it in sdcard?

Comment: You cannot work with UI outside of UI thread.

Comment: thank you Rahgunandan, it worked :)

Comment: @Raghunandan, actually I also don't know how to write the path of the file which exist in the same project.

Comment: you need to store it in asset folder.

Comment: @Raghunandan  **parser.parse("MyDB.txt", handler);**            MyDB.txt is in the assets folder but it says error opening trace file: No such file or directory.

Comment: `file:///android_asset/MyDB.txt` this you you need to refer.

Comment: @Raghunandan, it still gives the same error message: error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)

Comment: @Raghunandan the reason why it shows the same error is that, the parser opens a web browser therefore it cannot find my file on web browser.
How can I make it open my xml file (which is stored in the project folder) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please write this code in oncreate  method .

ctx = this;

And remove this code.

((Activity) ctx).setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

Comment: thank you, it solved my problem. Now I have another problem would you take a look at it?

 [link] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17471956/my-xml-parsersax-parser-parses-only-uri-source-how-can-i-parse-a-file-which-e [link]